# Question about Dynkin system

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \neq \varnothing$ and $D$ be a Dynkin System in $\Omega$. For all $E\in D$, show that $D(E)$ is closed under taking complements where:

$$D(E): \left\{F\in P(\Omega): F\cap E\in D\right\}$$

Is this question asking that the complement of $D(E) \in D$ as well? How do you show this?

Comment: The question is asking the following: if $F\in D(E)$, then the complement of $F$ is also an element of $D(E)$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let Ω≠∅ and D be a Dynkin System in Ω. For all E∈D, show that D(E) is closed under taking complements where D(E): {F∈P(Ω): F∩E∈D}.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709374/let-and-d-be-a-dynkin-system-in-for-all-ed-show-that-de-is-closed-und)

Comment: ok, then how do you show that the complement of F is also an element of D(E)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to use properties of Dynkin System, you want to prove that $F^c\cap E\in D$ but

$F^c\cap E=(\Omega \setminus  F )\cap E= (\Omega \cap E ) \setminus  (F\cap E )$

In the last term both $\Omega \cap E$ and $F\cap E$ belong to $D$  and $\Omega \cap E$ includes $F\cap E$. Now Dynkin systems are stable by set difference as long as the first term of the difference includes the second (for example [point 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system)), so we are done and $F^c \in D(E)$.

Best regards